# Compile Pro*C in AIX 7 (64bit)

Tags: c++

I try to migrate the old Pro*C program from HP to AIX, after changed some setting, I can make the binary file but fail to execute.  Seems I now facing wrong library used (lib32/libclntsh.a).

Here is the error

```
0509-036 Cannot load program PROGNAME because of the following errors:
0509-150   Dependent module SOMEPATH/lib32/libclntsh.a(shr.o) could not be loaded.
0509-103   The module has an invalid magic number.
```

I build the program by setting object mode to 64

```
export OBJECT_MODE=64
```

Here is the full image when I make the binary

```
/PATHA/bin/oraxlc   -O3  -q64 -DSS_64BIT_SERVER -I.      -c MYPROG.c "MYPROG.c", line 2051.25: 1506-342 (W) "/*" detected in comment.
/PATHA/bin/oraxlc  -o GLMJLUSB GLMJLUSB.o  -L/PATHA/lib/ -lclntsh  -lld -lm `cat /PATHA/lib/sysliblist`  -lm  -lc_r -lpthreads +DD64
/PATHB/bin/.orig/xlc: 1501-228 (W) input file +DD64 not found
```

Is there any way I can specify not to use the problem library, and use the 64bit version instead?

I don't know much about Pro*C and AIX, so any help is welcome.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Not really an answer yet, expect many edits).

Do you have a Makefile? If not, create one:

```
.SUFFIXES: .pc

PROC      = ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/proc
PROCFLAGS = code=ansi lines=yes

.pc.c:
        ${PROC} ${PROCFLAGS} $<
```

Keep improving it, until you can successfully precompile your *.pc files into *.c files.

Note: it is way easier, if you have GNU!make instead of prehistoric!make